# What is the electrical conductivity of a liquid Komatiite?

Tags: geophysics, geochemistry, volcanology, petrology

I am searching for previous work that has determined the electrical conductivity range for [komatiites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komatiite) at the surface. Does anyone have some values or references?